# Xcode's output different to IDLE's when using UTF-8 (Python 3)

Tags: python, xcode, utf-8

I am using Xcode 4.2 and IDLE under Mac OS 10.7 to compile Python 3 code, which is as follows:

```
#coding=utf-8
print("ľťď")
```

In spite of using the same interpreter, which is python 3.2.2, while IDLE returns the expected string `ľťď` (in fact, it works even without the first line—if I understand correctly, this version of Python uses utf-8 as default encoding), Xcode returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("\u013e\u0165\u010f")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I achieve the same output in Xcode, please?

Comment: Can you inspect `sys.stdout.encoding`?

Comment: I did `import sys` and `print(sys.stdout.encoding)` and now I am quite disoriented, because python3 through Terminal returns `UTF-8`, IDLE returns `us-ascii` (but still handles latin characters well!) and Xcode returns `US-ASCII` despite using the same executable as Terminal.

Comment: IDLE's behavior is strange. That the encoding for `stdout` differs is a function of what's consuming the output, not the Python program. I'm not familiar with Xcode, so I can't help your further.

Comment: @larsmans: Thank you anyway. :-) Hopefully someone will provide an explanation and possibly a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution thanks to [this article](http://mactip.blogspot.com/2010/01/python-and-utf-8-on-osx.html#links).

In case you experience the same issue, all you have to do is create a standard XML property list `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` (case sensitive, extension sensitive) with the key of `PYTHONIOENCODING` and string value `utf-8`. Do not forget to log out and log in before testing.

For more details, you may found these articles useful:

http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html

**environment.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PYTHONIOENCODING</key>
    <string>utf-8</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people are against the use of `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` (e.g., http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/macostex-archives/2011-September/047624.html)

On the other hand, I am in 10.6 using the ActiveState versions of python and tcl, and opening IDLE as an application gives "us-ascii" but opening it from the terminal ($ idle3) gives "utf-8", which may let you avoid the use of `environment.plist`.

Comment: What problems does it cause for example?

Comment: You might want to look a long discussion in this [2004 OS X TeX thread](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2004-May/005950.html)